# SQL Azure: Timeout expired

Tags: sql, azure

we have some cloud Services hosted in Windows Azure and also some Azure SQL database. At night (during 4:00 - 6:00 utc) there are running some Jobs to import data into database. Since some weeks all the Jobs fails with an timeout expired exception of the database. If I run the Jobs later (during 7:00 - 9:00 utc) on my local machine within the Emulator, all Jobs work without any Problems on the same database.

At the mport time is no much traffic from our site on the database server. The monitoring of the manage portal shows that there are not many open Connections, no throttled ones and no connection errors. There are much more traffic during my local runs.

The sys.event_log do not contains any errors or other possible issues.

Are there any logs or other Options to get more Information about why the Jobs failed at night?

***Update***
It seems, that the SQL Azure Server ignores the command timeout property. The Jobs start at 4:30 UTC and stops with an timeout exception at 4:37. But the query, which gets an timeout, has an command timeout of 1200 (20 minutes). And before starting the command, there are some downloads from an ftp-server, file parsing and other SQL queries.

Comment: I would really like to see if you could move the server to another afinity group or region, The document states that you can never be sure what other people are doing on that database server that might end up throttling you. Did you find any solution to this that you might want to share?

Comment: No, I don't find any solution. The problems don't occur at the moment, but I did'nt do anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Just to note that SQL Azure isn't a full version of MS SQL and does have some limitations. Most notable limitation is the infrastructure that its built on. Your SQL Azure DB will be hosted on a Small Instance server that has shared resource with hundreds of other users. Although there is a fair use policy on the machines it does take time for the servers to kick in.

My suggestion would be to have some way of determining if the Job is actually starting or if the connection pool is timing out prior to starting the job. I.E. create a jobs table that is inserted into to say its started and have this as the first action on your job.

Alternatively you could think about migrating to a VM setup in Azure. This is where you have a Small or Medium instance VM with a fully fledged version of MS SQL Server running on it. That way you can run your jobs against the server correctly and control you connection pooling more appropriately.